# Smoothing properties of analytic semigroups

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, sobolev-spaces, semigroups-of-operators

Assume $A$ is a second order operator, generator of a positive analytic semigroup on the $L^p$-spaces with $p\in (1,\infty)$ and domain $D(A_p)=W^{2,p}$. Do we have regularity estimates 
$\|T_p(t)f\|_{W^{k;p}}\leq t^{-\alpha} C \|f\|_{W^{l,q}}$ for $k\leq l$,possibly non-integral and $p\leq q$? In the case $p=q$ and $k,l$ integers 
such a result is obtained from the real characterization of analytic semigroups
(more precisely the property $\sup_{t>0} \|tAT(t)\|<\infty$). Also $L^p-L^q$-mapping properties are known. The point is to extend the results to $k,l$ non-integral.

Comment: For the record, at time of writing this question has attracted a vote to close as "unclear what you're asking". I strongly disagree with this reason given